# How to check status, install, and stop a program in ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server

Tags: command-line, installed-programs

I've been running a plex meida server for over 10 years. Over that decade, I've gotten married, bought a house, and had 3 kids, so due to lack of time involved, I never upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04.  Recently, my original SDD that held the OS finally crapped out. I gave it a proper memorial, and now that my wife and kids are all hooked on it, have been given the permission to upgrade everything. PLAY TIME. So I bought a new 500GB SSD and I upgraded from 16TB Sata raid, to 16TB SAS Raid (bought the controller and the drives). Everything went together beautifully, and the sas card works great, no issues there. My question is my newness to 20.04 and the way things work. Pulling from my 16.04 knowledge, I did the normal

```
    sudo apt install docker
```

and everything installed no issue. great. The logical thing I did next was check the status of the program by typing:

```
    sudo systemctl status docker
```

and I get the error

```
    tmataraza@plexstorage:~$ sudo apt-get install docker
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree 
    Reading state information... Done 
    The following additional packages will be installed: 
    wmdocker 
    The following NEW packages will be installed: 
    docker wmdocker
    0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    Need to get 14.3 kB of archives.
    After this operation, 58.4 kB of additional disk space will be used.
    Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
    Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 wmdocker amd64 1.5-2 [13.0 kB]
    Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 docker all 1.5-2 [1,316 B]
    Fetched 14.3 kB in 0s (38.1 kB/s)
    Selecting previously unselected package wmdocker.
    (Reading database ... 71232 files and directories currently installed.)
    Preparing to unpack .../wmdocker_1.5-2_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking wmdocker (1.5-2) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package docker.
    Preparing to unpack .../archives/docker_1.5-2_all.deb ...
    Unpacking docker (1.5-2) ...
    Setting up wmdocker (1.5-2) ...
    Setting up docker (1.5-2) ...
    Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
    tmataraza@plexstorage:~$ apt-cache policy docker
      docker:
        Installed: 1.5-2
        Candidate: 1.5-2
        Version table:
          *** 1.5-2 500
            500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
             100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
    tmataraza@plexstorage:~$ sudo systemctl status docker
    Unit docker.service could not be found.
```

So I am clueless. If I try to install again, I get docker is already installed, but if I try to check if its running, it says no service available. I scoured the webs and this site and I cant find anything on this subject. I was pretty fluent in 16.04 but apparently Im gonna be a newb again with 20.04. Out of curiosity I tried this same process on plex. Everything worked on install and I know plex is running cuz I can get to the I.P directly and configure my server, however, when I do the status command, I get

```
    tmataraza@plexstorage:~$ sudo systemctl status plexmediaserver
    Unit plexmediaserver.service could not be found.
```

Clueless. What am I missing?? Also, it's probably dumb newbie oversight, so dont hold back. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You install wrong package. Try:

`sudo apt install docker.io`

Answer (score 0):

This is to be expected. You installed [a system tray for KDE3/Gnome2 applications](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/wmdocker.1.html), not a container engine

To install Docker *the container engine*, you'll want to do this:

0. Open a Terminal (if not already open)
1. Install some of the `apt` HTTPS prerequisites (if they're not already installed):

   ```
   sudo apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common
   ```
2. Add the GPG key for the official Docker repository:

   ```
   curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
3. Add the Docker repository:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable"
   ```
4. Update `apt`:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
5. Install Docker, the container engine:

   ```
   sudo apt install docker-ce
   ```

Once that's all said and done, you should be able to do this:

```
$ sudo service docker status
```

Which will (hopefully) give you something like this:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-01-29 01:28:31 JST; 1 weeks 0 days ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 1724 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 13
     Memory: 39.6M
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             └─1724 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I appreciate the immediate response, and I did all that, as I followed the install instructions for docker and 20.04 on Digital Ocean. 

HOWEVER, it seems your repo has something different in the code because on copy/paste (to remove all errors possible) I tried the DO again, I got the error:

Comment: I got and error saying there were no packages available, but your code worked without issue. I scanned the steps and nothing looks different between your code and theirs. THANK YOU FOR THE INSIGHT